# How can I pass data from a thread to the parent process?

Tags: c++, c, pipe, signals, unix

I have a main process that uses a single thread library and I can only the library functions from the main process. I have a thread spawned by the parent process that puts info it receives from the network into a queue.

I need to able to tell the main process that something is on the queue. Then it can access  the queue and process the objects. The thread cannot process those objects because the library can only be called by one process.

I guess I need to use pipes and signals. I also read from various newsgroups that I need to use a 'self-trick' pipe.

How should this scenario be implemented?

#### A more specific case of the following post:

> [How can unix pipes be used between main process and thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965316/how-can-unix-pipes-be-used-between-main-process-and-thread)

Comment: A dear "down-voter", is there anything I can do to improve the quality of this question? and what exactly you didn't like about my question? thanks

Comment: Rich, it is NOT related but sort of a continuation. Please let me know before you edit my posts. Thanks, mom

Comment: Are you talking about threads or processes ? It's a bit confusing in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a simple FIFO (named pipe)? The main process will automatically block until it can read something.
If it shouldn't block, it must be possible to poll instead, but maybe it will suck CPU. There probably exists an efficient library for this purpose.

I wouldn't recommend using signals because they are easy to get wrong. If you want to use them anyway, the easiest way I've found is:

- Mask all signals in every thread,
- A special thread handles signals with `sigwait()`. It may have to wake up another thread which will handle the signal, e.g. using condition variables.

The advantage is that you don't have to worry anymore about which function is safe to call from the handler.

Comment: This is close to what I need.  It should not block.

Answer (score 0):

The "optimal" solution depends quite a bit on your concrete setup. Do you have one process with a main thread and a child thread or do you have one parent process and a child process? Which OS and which thread library do you use?

The reason for the last question is that the current C++03 standard has no notion of a 'thread'. This means in particular that whatever solution your OS and your thread library offer are platform specific. The most portable solutions will only hide these specifics from you in their implementation.

In particular, C++ has no notion of threads in its memory model, nor does it have a notion of  atomic operations, synchronization, ordered memory accesses, race conditions etc.

Chances are, however, that whatever library you are using already provides a solution for your problem on your platform.

Comment: I thought it was obvious from the question that I am using POSIX/LINUX and pthread library... ugh, sorry if it wasn't, I will clarify the question

Answer (score -1):

I highly suggest you used a thread-safe queue such as [this one](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) (article and source code). I have personally used it and it's very simple to use. The API consist in simple methods such as push(), try_pop(), wait_and_pop() and empty().

Note that it is based on [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/thread.html).